# How to turn off INFO logging in SparkR 1.5.0?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

How can I turn off INFO logging level in sparkR. I want to keep only ERROR logging level

In pyspark, this is done like this

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
```

I am using SparkR version 1.5.0

Comment: the `setLogLevel` function for sparkR is available since version 2.0.0 (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/setLogLevel.html). But not for Spark 1.5.0

Comment: how to do this in 1.5.0

Comment: chresse, any help available?

Comment: It should be possible to use the Java API from R via rJava, but it's probably easier to upgrade.

Comment: reactormonk, I didn't understand what ur saying, do you want me to use java?